# []byte{10} or []byte("\n") vs []byte{92, 110}

Tags: arrays, go, newline, bytebuffer

I'm working with `github.com/tarm/serial` to interface with some serial instrumentation.  In development, I'm working with the `/dev/ttyp0` and `/dev/ptyp0` pair, where my go process connects to one and I use `screen` to connect to the other.  I've written a function that, combined with `serial.Config.ReadTimeout`, reads for up to `ReadTimeout` or a given byte sequence is received.  That function is:

```golang
func readToTermination(s serial.Port, termination []byte, rate time.Duration) []byte {
    var out []byte
    lterm := len(termination)
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 128)
        n, _ := s.Read(buf)
        out = append(out, buf[:n]...)
        l := len(out)
        if l >= lterm {
            if bytes.Compare(out[l-lterm:], termination) == 0 {
                break
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(rate)
    }
    return out
}
```

This avoids burning up CPU cycles doing nothing with a debounce.  When I test with `termination = []byte("\n")` and screen, the `break` never triggers because it turns into `[]byte{97, 11}` (two distinct elements, something like screen flushing after each keystroke).  On the other hand, if I do something like `echo "foo" > /dev/ptyp0`, the break triggers correctly.  Echo implicitly seems to be sending a `\n`, or the closing of the connection does so.  I see `\r\n` for `echo foo` and `\r\n\r\n` for `echo "foo\n"`.

So my question is:

(1) why is there a difference in behavior here?

(2) how do I get the behavior I really am after with a carriage return for the termination?  Perhaps I should use EOT instead?  A human will never be typing into this directly.

Comment: `[]byte("\n")` certainly is not transformed to 2 bytes: https://play.golang.org/p/MAS6nfl4XJ2

Comment: Yes, I know.  I’m asking if there is a way to get a sequence of []byte{97, 110}, “\” and “n” as distinct bytes, to compare to []byte(“\n”) as truthy.

Comment: 97 in ascii is `a` and 110 in ascii is `n`. How does it correlate with `\n`? If you meant 92 and 110, then probably the best you could do is to manually substitute `\n` with `\\n`

Comment: why don t you handle EOF ? Is 128 the message size or arbitrary ? the sleep should run only if n<1, if necessary at all. can you provide a minimal reproducible example that i can run (assuming linux) ?